# Automatically refresh Statistics query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a Statistic  on my main page, along with a list of buttons for items. If you press the button for an item, it calls a PHP file, runs a query and set the item's status to 1 in the database. With the Statistics box I can track how many items has been selected.

```
  $selected = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT SUM(stat) FROM table1'); 
  $selected_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selected); 
  $selected_sum = $selected_row['SUM(stat)'];
```

It works fine, but it only refresh the data in the box when the page refreshes. I want the data to be refreshed immidietly. How can achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Use AJAX to make the request in the background, and then update your document with the data your server-side endpoint returned.

Comment: FYI your question has nothing to do with PHP or SQL